# After Update of running update -- all anaconda + Spyder disappeared

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I run an update today as the systems have not been updated for a while and now after running "conda update -- all" in the anaconda prompt - everything seems to be away. I can find neither Spyder or Anaconda prompt in the Windows search bar. :(

Do i need to deinstall and install everything again? Please help!!!

Comment: Did the command run successfully? Maybe to see the updated menu entries a machine restart is needed

Comment: yes it did. In the end in deinstalled and installed everything again..